# Issue with dropdown submitting selected value - Django/Python

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications

I am trying to get the selected value in the dropdown to add to the cart. The way I have it prints out different dropdowns but submits the data into the cart. I just want one dropdown that submits the selected value. Thank you.

```
{% for product in products %}
 <form class = 'pull-right' method ='GET' action='{% url "update_cart" product.slug 1 %}'>

          <select id="menulist">


            <option>{{ product.name }}:  ${{ product.price }}</option>

            {% endfor %}
          </select>

        <button type = 'submit' class ="btn btn-info btn-md" class ='pull-right'>Add To Order</button>
           </form>
```

Comment: the forloop should be around the options.

Comment: open your browser developer tools and look at the HTML that django created. you'll understand what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simply two things need.
First, You should setup option's value. second, `forloop` should target only option, not whole form.

```
<form class = 'pull-right' method ='GET' action='{% url "update_cart" product.slug 1 %}'>
    <select id="menulist" name="{# your select's name here #}">
        {% for product in products %}
            <option value="{{ product.id|slugify }}">{{ product.name }}:  ${{ product.price }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type = 'submit' class ="btn btn-info btn-md" class ='pull-right'>Add To Order</button>
</form>
```

This code snippet show two different point. 1. option have value, select has name. 2. forloop should in select tags.